# How can I get recentf-mode to work with emacs server/client?

Tags: emacs

I like using `recentf`  mode in Emacs which produces a list of files I have recently opened. This list is persistent between sessions, so I can get to files I used a fairly long time ago.

However, I recently started using Emacsclient to connect to an Emacs server which is automatically turned on when I log it. Overall, this was a big improvement. However, `recentf` mode started missing *most* of the files I opened whenever I restarted my computer. It remembers *some* of them, and I cannot see a pattern in which files get recorded.

How can I fix this behavior? How can I get it to record *all* the files I visit and remember them between sessions?

Comment: I have the same problem, would be great to see a solution!

Comment: I tried this using `emacs -nw`, loading server and recentf, then running `recentf-mode 1` and `server-start` in that order and was not able to reproduce your problem.  Can you post your .emacs file somewhere (such as a pastebin) along with an example of how you're starting emacs and emacsclient?

Comment: Here is my [.emacs](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~tikhon/.emacs) file. I'm using Fedora and I installed Emacs with Yum; it created a launcher for Emacs Client and that's what I use. The launcher just runs `emacsclient -c --alternate-editor="" %f`. The problem might be with my not closing Emacs before turning my computer off, but I'm not sure. Manually killing Emacs before shutting off seems to help, but that's not a great solution.

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't see server-start in your .emacs, I assume it's getting started with --daemon when you log in.  I'm suspecting some kind of ordering issue with enabling recentf and starting the server.

Answer (score 9):

I was having this exact same problem, and I solved it by making two changes.  First following [this post](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecentFiles#toc1), I created a function to automatically invoke `recentf-save-list` on a timer.  Thus every few minutes, we automatically re-write the ~/.recentf file:

```
(run-at-time nil (* 5 60) 'recentf-save-list)
```

The other thing I did was to add a shutdown script to my display manager (lightdm) that gracefully closed the emacs server every time I logout or shutdown.  The way you do this will depend on your display manager, but my script simply looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
emacsclient -e "(save-buffers-kill-emacs)"
```

It would also be nice to have a hook that automatically re-ran `recentf-save-list` every time a client "disconnected" from the server, but I couldn't figure out the proper hooks.

Comment: It's `server-done-hook`. Personally I use `server-visit-hook`